# Why does this python script run out of memory?

Tags: java, python, memory, minecraft, decompiler

I know next to nothing about Python, so I've come here to ask you all how to change this. I will provide fragments of files, which should be all you need to solve this.

main.py - does all the logging, gets everything done

```
commands.logger.info('> Applying SpecialSource')
        commands.applyss(side, keep_lvt=keep_lvt, keep_generics=keep_generics)
```

commands.py - has all the defs

```
def applyss(self, side, reobf=False, srg_names=False, in_jar=None, out_jar=None, keep_lvt=False, keep_generics=False):
        """Apply ss to the given side"""
        cplk = {CLIENT: self.cpathclient, SERVER: self.cpathserver}
        cfgsrg  = {CLIENT: self.srgsclient, SERVER: self.srgsserver}
        deobsrg = {CLIENT: self.deobsrgclient, SERVER: self.deobsrgserver}
        reobsrg = {CLIENT: self.reobsrgclient, SERVER: self.reobsrgserver}
        rsrgsrg = {CLIENT: self.reobsrgclientsrg, SERVER: self.reobsrgserversrg}
        if in_jar is None:
            if reobf:
                in_jar = {CLIENT: self.cmpjarclient, SERVER: self.cmpjarserver}[side]
            else:
                in_jar = {CLIENT: self.jarclient, SERVER: self.jarserver}[side]
        if out_jar is None:
            if reobf:
                out_jar = {CLIENT: self.reobfjarclient, SERVER: self.reobfjarserver}[side]
            else:
                out_jar = {CLIENT: self.rgclientout, SERVER: self.rgserverout}[side]
        if reobf:
            cmd = self.cmdssreobf
            if srg_names:
                identifier = 'RGMCPSRG'
                srg = rsrgsrg[side]
            else:
                identifier = 'RGMCP'
                srg = reobsrg[side]
        else:
            cmd = self.cmdss
            identifier = None
            srg = cfgsrg[side]
        # add specialsource.jar to copy of client or server classpath
        sscp = [self.specialsource] + cplk[side]
        sscp = os.pathsep.join(sscp)
        forkcmd = cmd.format(classpath=sscp, injar=in_jar, outjar=out_jar, identifier=identifier, mapfile=srg)
        if not keep_lvt:
            forkcmd += ' --kill-lvt'
        if not keep_generics:
            forkcmd += ' --kill-generics'
        try:
            self.runcmd(forkcmd)
            if not reobf:
                shutil.copyfile(cfgsrg[side], deobsrg[side])
                shutil.copyfile(deobsrg[side], reobsrg[side])
        except CalledProcessError as ex:
            self.logger.error('')
            self.logger.error('== ERRORS FOUND ==')
            self.logger.error('')
            for line in ex.output.splitlines():
                if line.strip():
                    if line[0] != '#':
                        self.logger.error(line)
            self.logger.error('==================')
            self.logger.error('')
            raise
```

If you haven't already figured it out, this is MCP, or Minecraft Coder Pack. The problem is, when decompiling the server jar, it runs out of memory during the `> Applying SpecialSource` stage. I have no idea where it says anything like `java -jar SpecialSource.jar` or whatever, and was hoping you could tell me where to look for it.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your python is up to date, and, what OS are you running? I had this issue, and it was a mixture of outdated software, and MCP mistook some libraries for Windows, so things messed up. If you are on a mac/linux, search in your MCP folder for windows and replace windows with your OS name. This worked for me.